# How to use case_when() for exclusive multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, case

In our study, a participant is regarded as a case with hypertension when he/she has a history of hypertension, or systolic blood pressure >130 mmHg, or diastolic blood pressure >80 mmHg, or recieves antihypertensive treatment. I create the final hypertension status by using two different methods as listed below, and the results of method 1 is correct but not method 2. My question is how to create the final hypertension status by using the case_when() function in method 2?

```
#-------------------------- data set
  # id: id number of participants
  # hptn_his: self-reported history of hypertension (0 means no, 1 or 2 mean yes)
  # sbp: systolic blood pressure (mmHg)
  # dbp: diastolic blood pressure (mmHg)
  # treat: whether recieved the antihypertensive treatment (0 means no, 1 means yes)
  id<-c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24)
  hptn_his<-c(0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 1, 1, 1)
  sbp<-c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 110, 105, 115, NA, NA, NA, NA, 109, 102, 140, 136, 150, 126, 112, 147, NA, NA, 155, 124)
  dbp<-c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 61, 62, 84, NA, NA, NA, NA, 75, 67, 74, 67, 58, 50, 45, 48, NA, NA, 80, 74)
  treat<-c(NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA)
  
  mydata<-as.data.frame(cbind(id,hptn_his,sbp,dbp,treat))
  
  mydata
  
      id hptn_his sbp dbp treat
  1   1        0  NA  NA    NA
  2   2       NA  NA  NA    NA
  3   3       NA  NA  NA    NA
  4   4       NA  NA  NA     1
  5   5       NA  NA  NA    NA
  6   6       NA 110  61    NA
  7   7        2 105  62    NA
  8   8        2 115  84     1
  9   9        2  NA  NA    NA
  10 10        0  NA  NA    NA
  11 11        0  NA  NA     1
  12 12       NA  NA  NA    NA
  13 13       NA 109  75    NA
  14 14        0 102  67    NA
  15 15        0 140  74    NA
  16 16        0 136  67    NA
  17 17        0 150  58    NA
  18 18        0 126  50    NA
  19 19        0 112  45    NA
  20 20       NA 147  48     1
  21 21        0  NA  NA     1
  22 22        1  NA  NA    NA
  23 23        1 155  80     1
  24 24        1 124  74    NA
  
  #-------------------------- method 1, correct
  mydata<-within(mydata,{ 
    hptn1<-NA 
    hptn1[hptn_his==0]<-0
    hptn1[hptn_his==1|hptn_his==2|sbp>130|dbp>80|treat==1]<-1
  })
  
  table(mydata$hptn1)
  
  0  1 
  5 13
  
  #-------------------------- method 2, incorrect 
  library("dplyr")
  mydata<-mydata%>%
    mutate(
      hptn2=case_when(hptn_his==0~0,
                      hptn_his==1|hptn_his==2|sbp>130|dbp>80|treat==1~1,
                      TRUE~NA_real_))
  
  table(mydata$hptn2)
  
  0  1 
  10  8
  
  #-------------------------- comparison
  # hptn1: hypertension status by method 1 (0 means no, 1 means yes), correct
  # hptn2: hypertension status by method 2 (0 means no, 1 means yes), incorrect
  mydata
  
      id hptn_his sbp dbp treat hptn1 hptn2
  1   1        0  NA  NA    NA     0     0
  2   2       NA  NA  NA    NA    NA    NA
  3   3       NA  NA  NA    NA    NA    NA
  4   4       NA  NA  NA     1     1     1
  5   5       NA  NA  NA    NA    NA    NA
  6   6       NA 110  61    NA    NA    NA
  7   7        2 105  62    NA     1     1
  8   8        2 115  84     1     1     1
  9   9        2  NA  NA    NA     1     1
  10 10        0  NA  NA    NA     0     0
  11 11        0  NA  NA     1     1     0
  12 12       NA  NA  NA    NA    NA    NA
  13 13       NA 109  75    NA    NA    NA
  14 14        0 102  67    NA     0     0
  15 15        0 140  74    NA     1     0
  16 16        0 136  67    NA     1     0
  17 17        0 150  58    NA     1     0
  18 18        0 126  50    NA     0     0
  19 19        0 112  45    NA     0     0
  20 20       NA 147  48     1     1     1
  21 21        0  NA  NA     1     1     0
  22 22        1  NA  NA    NA     1     1
  23 23        1 155  80     1     1     1
  24 24        1 124  74    NA     1     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case_when` returns on the first value that is true. For the records that appear wrong using your second method, these occur when `hptn_hist==0` triggers first before the additional question.

Short answer, swap the order:

```r
mydata<-mydata%>%
  mutate(
    hptn3=case_when(hptn_his==1|hptn_his==2|sbp>130|dbp>80|treat==1~1,
                    hptn_his==0~0,
                    TRUE~NA_real_))
```

More detailed explanation:

- In your first approach you are using over-writing. Some values from `hptn1[hptn_his==0]<-0` are then overwritten by `hptn1[hptn_his==1|hptn_his==2|sbp>130|dbp>80|treat==1]<-1`. This is the correct order if later values overwrite earlier onces.
- In your second approach, `case_when` returns only the first true value. So later values can not overwrite earlier ones. Hence the correct order is `hptn_his==1|hptn_his==2|sbp>130|dbp>80|treat==1` before `hptn_his==0`.

Another was to think of this:

```r
case_when(condition1 ~ 1,
          condition2 ~ 2,
          condition3 ~ 3,
          ...)
```

Is equivalent to:

```r
case_when(condition1 ~ 1,
          !condition1 & condition2 ~ 2,
          !condition1 & !condition2 & condition3 ~ 3,
          ...)
```

Comment: Thank you Simon! This is really helpful! I just think case_when () is cool but sometimes uncontrolled.

Comment: Besides, the structure of case_when() is expected to be more complex when the number of exclusive multiple conditions increases. Are there some other functions can be used in library("dplyr") (or linked to dplyr) for the over-writing conditions except for case_when()?

Comment: I am not aware of any over-writing approach equivalent to `case_when`. In general, I would recommend non-over-writing approaches as they tend to be easier to understand.